# Start more than one servlet with Jetty

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jetty, osgi

I use the Felix implementation of OSGi together with Maven. I use the maven bundle plugin to wire up the dependencies (i.e. the Service-Component header). I use the following to register a servlet

```
<Service-Component>
 com.mycompany.MyServlet;
 provide:=javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;immediate:=true;
 http=org.osgi.service.http.HttpService
</Service-Component>
```

However, I want to run a second servlet using the same HTTP service. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Uh, servlets are created on demand... Could you rephrase your problem?

Comment: I am not really into Java's world and that's why probably I don't know how to express my necessity :-) I have Felix, Maven, and Jetty that play together. How can I register servlets as dependencies? What does 'on demand' mean?

Comment: "How can I register servlets as dependencies" <-- I don't understand that. As to "on demand", it simply means that if you have bound a servlet to a path into your web application it is the servlet container's role to spawn as many servles as necessary to both handle requests and obey the limits you have imposed in the container's configuration. I hope I have made myself clear...

Comment: I mean, I have two different servlets, which are supposed to handle requests at two different paths. But if I try to register the second servlet in the <Service-Component>, Jetty tries to create a new HTTP service (as I can see from the log) and fails as there is already one listening on 127.0.0.1

Comment: this is really more of an osgi-ism then anything related to jetty...how to do this is simple and clear in jetty, far less so in the world of osgi

Comment: @jessemcconnell Good job the question already has an OSGi tag on it, eh? Anyway it seems pretty clear in the world of OSGi also, as the answer from forty-two below demonstrates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: simple, add more clauses to the Service-Component header:

```
 <Service-Component>
  com.mycompany.MyServlet1;
    provide:=javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;immediate:=true;
    http=org.osgi.service.http.HttpService,
  com.mycompany.MyServlet2;
    provide:=javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;immediate:=true;
    http=org.osgi.service.http.HttpService
 </Service-Component>
```

Better answer. Apache Felix has the White board bundle. This bundle tracks Servlet services (not HttpServlet! but it does track Filter services) in the service registry and automatically adds them to the present Http Service services. So all you do is register under Servlet.class with a 'alias' property for the alias. This also then does not require you to be immediate, making it lazy until the servlet is used. This is advocated in 42's answer but would look like this with the header approach:

```
 <Service-Component>
  com.mycompany.MyServlet1;
    provide:=javax.servlet.servlet.Servlet; 
    properties="alias=/path"
 </Service-Component>
```

Best answer, use the OSGi DS annotations to register your servlet:

```
 @Component(provide=Servlet.class, properties='alias=/path')
 public void MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rsp) {
        ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the felic [SCR annotations](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html) together  with the maven-scr-plugin

Then you can simply annotate your serlvets:

```
@Component(immediate=true)
@Service(Servlet.class)
@Property(name="alias", value="/path1")
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    ...
}

@Component(immediate=true)
@Service(Servlet.class)
@Property(name="alias", value="/path2")
public class Servlet2 extends HttpServlet {
    ...
}
```

It also assumes that you have the Felix [HTTP whiteboard](http://apache.mirror3.ip-only.net//felix/org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard-2.2.0.jar) bundle installed. HTTP whiteboard will detect all services of type javax.servlet.Servlet, and automatically register them with the HTTP service.